# Get unresolved imports

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing eclipse plugin that looks for unresolved imports in all source files. 
I found that it can be helpful to use `IProblem` or `IMarker` objects. Here's code example

```
public IMarker[] findJavaProblemMarkers(ICompilationUnit cu) 
  throws CoreException {
  IResource javaSourceFile = cu.getUnderlyingResource();
  IMarker[] markers = 
     javaSourceFile.findMarkers(IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER,
        true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
}
```

frome [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_classpath.htm)

I don't know how I can get info from `IProblem` or `IMarker` about which import cause the compilation problem (unresolved import).

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_classpath.htm

There are a list of different int values in the IProblem interface representing different errors; if you could get the errorcodes of a file somehow, you could use them. (Example, ImportNotVisible, ImportNotFound, etc.). Just check if the error ID matches one of the error ID's for import failures there.

Comment: But how I can get info about error from IMarker? IMarker has `getId()` method, but it's completly other number than `IProblem.ImportNotFound`.

Answer (score 0):

An IMarker knows the line number and start and stop chars for the java source marked by the IMarker.  You can take the substring of the java source string and, if the marker type indicates that it's a problem with the class or import, you can search the project's classpath for a class or package matching (or similar to) that substring.

Comment: If this didn't solve your problem please let me know and I'll delete the answer.  I don't want to confuse future readers.